# Использование WM_COPYDATA только между процессами одного и того-же приложения

Tags: c++, winapi, inter-process

Я изучаю программирование под Win32. Хочу написать приложение которое может обмениваться сообщениями `WM_COPYDATA` между собственными экземплярами. Ниже приведен примерный код, как это делается исходя из многочисленных примеров.

Объявляем комманды:

```
enum COMMANDS { COMMAND1, COMMAND2, COMMAND3 };
```

Посылаем команду:

```
HWND hWnd = FindWindow(...);
if (hWnd != NULL) {
  COPYDATASTRUCT cds = {0};
  cds.dwData = COMMAND1;
  SendMessage(hWnd, WM_COPYDATA, (WPARAM)hwnd, (LPARAM)(LPVOID)&cds);
  CloseHandle(hWnd);
}
```

Обрабатываем команды:

```
LRESULT Wndproc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
  
  switch (uMsg) {
    ...
    case WM_COPYDATA:
      COPYDATASTRUCT* pcds = (COPYDATASTRUCT*)lParam;
      switch (pcds->dwData) {
        case COMMAND1: ... ; break;
        case COMMAND2: ... ; break;
        case COMMAND3: ... ; break;
      } 
      return TRUE;
    ...
  }

  return FALSE;
}
```

Однако есть один вопрос. На этапе посылки команды другому экземпляру приложения требуется знать `HANDLE` его окна. Для нахождения его в примерах используется функция `FindWindow`. Но как я понимаю, этот вариант не гарантирует уникальности. В связи с этим у меня несколько вопросов:

1. Правильно ли я понимаю, что теоретически, в системе могут существовать окна сторонних приложений с тем же классом и именем, если другой разработчик использовал схожие имена. И в таком случае `FindWindow` теоретически может вернуть описатели окон сторонних праложений и `WM_COPYDATA` отправится к сторонним приложениям. Конечно я понимаю, что вероятность не велика, но теоретически это же может приводить к сбоям, если и стороннее ОДНОИМЕННОЕ приложение как-то обрабатывает сообщения `WM_COPYDATA`.
2. Каким образом можно сделать, чтобы приложение находило только свои собстенные экземпляры запущенные в системе и гарарнтированно посылало сообщение `WM_COPYDATA` лишь только им.

Comment: Ввести протокол опознавания свой-чужой - например, послать запрос "?" и ожидать ответа "!".

Comment: Так вопрос в том как именно это сделать? Я не хочу, чтобы сторонние приложения вообще каким то образом получали любые сообщения из моего приложения. Нужно идентифицировать только группу запущенных процессов моего приложения и отослать сообщение только им. А то, что должен быть некий протокол это я и сам знаю.

Comment: ОК. Тогда вы можете создать скрытое окно для приёма сообщений, назначив ему имя на основe предварительно сгенерированного GUID. Этот гуид - практически точно ваш и не повторится.

Comment: Не уверен, что это универсальное решение. А если приложение вообще без окон?

Comment: вы же wm_copydata посылаете окну. Даже в консольном приложении можно завести скрытое окно.Однако способов IPC немало - вы можете использовать MMF, пайпы, сокеты - но во всех случаях нужна некая идентификация. В общем-то, GUID и придумали, чтобы был универсальный метод получения уникальной комбинации.

Comment: `WM_COPYDATA` на мой взгляд не лучшее решение для IPC. Я не нашел как отвечает `RegisterClass` при вводе существующего названия, но скорее всего он вернет ошибку. Но также я уверен, что можно создать много окон с одним и тем же классом и именем. Выше правильно написали, либо GUID использовать, либо людой другой способ коммуникации. Т.е. при использовании своего `FindWindow` по классу вы всегда будете получать только свои окна.